# Displaying value from Mysql db to Html5 bootstrap using PHP/Jquery

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, bootstrap-4

Here's my codes

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Control Panel</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- NProgress -->
    <link href="css/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <link href="css/green.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Datatables -->
    <link href="css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/buttons.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/fixedHeader.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/scroller.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Theme Style -->
    <link href="css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body class="nav-md">
    <div class="container body">
      <div class="main_container">
        <div class="col-md-12 left_col">
          <div class="left_col scroll-view">
              <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="x_panel">
                  <div class="x_content">
                    <table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>S/N</th>
                          <th>Date</th>
                          <th>IP Address</th>
                          <th>Activation</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td>get data from db</td>
                          <td>get data from db</td>
                          <td>get data from db</td>
                          <td>get data from db</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FastClick -->
    <script src="js/fastclick.js"></script>
    <!-- NProgress -->
    <script src="js/nprogress.js"></script>
    <!-- iCheck -->
    <script src="js/icheck.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Datatables -->
    <script src="js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/buttons.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.keyTable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/responsive.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vfs_fonts.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme Scripts -->
    <script src="js/custom.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$servername = "remotedbIP";
$username = "root";
$password = "Password";
$dbname = "installation";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, date, ip, activate FROM software";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - date: " . $row["date"]. " - ip: " . $row["ip"].  " - activate: " . $row["activate"]. " <br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

I am trying to display the data retrieved by the php file using the html table format with bootstrap. I am not sure how to do that. I tried to follow a few guidelines but I couldn't figure out. Any direction towards the right guideline or help would be really appreciated.

Also I am trying to hide the ID from the mysql db and instead show a locally displayed serial number, is it possible to achieve that, if yes how?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 .Put your database connection codes in database_connection.php

```
$servername = "remotedbIP";
$username = "root";
$password = "Password";
$dbname = "installation";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Step 2. Than include the connection in header of  index page

```
include("database_connection.php");
```

Step 3. add these php code inside table tbody And remove the previous codes

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT id, date, ip, activate FROM software";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td> $row['id'] </td>";
         echo "<td> $row['date'] </td>";
         echo "<td> $row['ip'] </td>";
         echo "<td> $row['activate'] </td>";
         echo "</tr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: I mentioned the image link above. Please see. It comes like that.

Comment: oh i see. its because your index page in in .html extension change it to index.php

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) on line 56    I get this error once I change it to php

Comment: okay can you send me the files so that i can debug it and send it to you .

Comment: sure how do I do that? which script hosting site do you prefer ?

Comment: you can sends the files in my email. rawscripterx@gmail.com